# How to determine what bit is set?

Tags: math, binary, binary-data

What does "this bit is set" even mean and how should one determine what bits are set and which aren't.

Example: 
If I had the binary 0001 0010 = decimal 18
How do I know bits 1 and 4 are set?

Clarification: in my head and no coding

Comment: You can perform a bit AND operation with the corresponding powers of 2.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is convert a number from base 10 to base 2.
Here's a quick tutorial to do this :
http://math.about.com/od/calculuslessons/a/changebase.htm

Answer (score 0):

With your "in my head, no coding" clarification, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19273450/1032643)
 sums it up pretty well. It's still unclear if you want to know which bits are set from a binary number or a decimal one, I'll assume the latter, since seeing if a bit is set from a binary number is trivial. I'd add a couple of things to Boris' answer:

- A bit K of a number B is set if its value is 1, meaning you need to add the K power of 2 to your sum in order to get B. Keep in mind that in binary notation, every positive integer is represented as a sum of powers of 2. No power of 2 can be represented as sum of lesser powers of 2, thus making the binary representation of a number unique.
- You can instantly know if the the first bit is set, as it defines parity (0-even, 1-odd).
- You can know the greatest set bit by finding the maximum power of 2 that is less than the number you are analyzing. No bits beyond this one will be set (if they were, they would be greater than the power of 2 that you found, thus voiding its maximality).
- From here on, you basically do as Boris told you. It's a linear check over every power of two.

I think you may want to read about [this](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_%28mathematics%29) to have a better understanding of what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the method based on substracting numbers.

You know powers of 2:

```
2^0 =   1
2^1 =   2
2^2 =   4
2^3 =   8
2^4 =  16
2^5 =  32
2^6 =  64
2^7 = 128
```

Then take any number you want and try substract the maximum from the powers of 2 but result has to be greater or equal to 0.

Example:

1. Take the number 18.
2. Try substract 128: 18-128 = -110, it means you cann't substract 128, the 7-th bit is 0
3. Try substract  64:  18-64 =  -46, it means you cann't substract  64, the 6-th bit is 0
4. Try substract  32:  18-32 =  -14, it means you cann't substract  32, the 5-th bit is 0
5. Try substract  16:  18-16 =    2, it means you **CAN** substract  16, the 4-th bit is 1
6. continue with the rest: 18-16 2
7. Try substract  8: 2-8 = -6, it means you cann't substract 8, the 3-rd bit is 0
8. Try substract  4: 2-4 = -2, it means you cann't substract 4, the 2-nd bit is 0
9. Try substract  2: 2-2 = 0, it means you **CAN** substract 2, the 1-st bit is 1
10. The rest of the number is 0, then every following bits are 0